# Lucene/MySQL Integration - Play Framework (Scala)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, lucene, playframework-2.0, hibernate-search

Has anyone tried to integrate Lucene and MySQL with Play Framework through Scala?

The challenge i am finding is how to keep the lucene index in synch with the DB. This is possible using Hibernate Search, but that's not possible/advised when using Play-Scala.

Any guidance/advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: maybe i should rephrase the question.. is there an Hibernate-Search/Compass type of API available for Play Framework (Scala)?

Comment: What problems do you encounter using Hibernate Search directly from Scala as you would from Java? Granted, using a Java API in your Scala won't give you pretty Scala code, but there should be no problem for it to actually work.